# Replace a block in a matrix

Tags: matrix, core-language

Is this the proper way to replace a block of a matrix with new entries?

```
i = IdentityMatrix[8];
i[[1 ;; 2, 1 ;; 2]] = {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}/2
```

If so, why does this return

```
{{1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, -(1/2)}}
```

although

```
i
```

returns:

{{1/2, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1/2, -(1/2), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
   1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 1}}

More specifically, here is where I am experiencing the this problem. I start with:

```
indmat[n_] := Module[{b, c},
  b = Transpose[{{1, 1}/2}];
  c = Transpose[{{1, -1}/2}];
  While[Min[Dimensions[b]] < n/2,
   b = ArrayFlatten[{{b, 0}, {0, b}}]];
  While[Min[Dimensions[c]] < n/2,
   c = ArrayFlatten[{{c, 0}, {0, c}}]];
  ArrayFlatten[{{b, c}}]
  ]
```

Which works:

```
indmat[8]
```

This produces:

```
{{1/2, 0, 0, 0, 1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {1/2, 0, 0, 0, -(1/2), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/
  2, 0, 0, 0, 1/2, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, -(1/2), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/2,
   0, 0, 0, 1/2, 0}, {0, 0, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, -(1/2), 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/2, 
  0, 0, 0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 0, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, -(1/2)}}
```

Next, consider:

```
s = 8;
num = 3;
m = IdentityMatrix[s];
a = IdentityMatrix[s];
i = s/2^num;
While[i <= s/2,
 a[[1 ;; 2 i, 1 ;; 2 i]] = indmat[2*i];
 m = a.m;
 i = 2*i]
```

Which works, producing:

```
{{1/8, 1/8, 1/4, 0, 1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {1/8, 1/8, 1/4, 0, -(1/2), 0, 0, 
  0}, {1/8, 1/8, -(1/4), 0, 0, 1/2, 0, 0}, {1/8, 1/8, -(1/4), 0, 
  0, -(1/2), 0, 0}, {1/8, -(1/8), 0, 1/4, 0, 0, 1/2, 0}, {1/8, -(1/8),
   0, 1/4, 0, 0, -(1/2), 0}, {1/8, -(1/8), 0, -(1/4), 0, 0, 0, 1/
  2}, {1/8, -(1/8), 0, -(1/4), 0, 0, 0, -(1/2)}}
```

But this, which seems quite identical to me:

```
wavmat[n_] := Module[{s, num, m, a, i},
  s = n;
  num = Log[n]/Log[2.];
  m = IdentityMatrix[s];
  a = IdentityMatrix[s];
  i = s/2^num;
  While[i <= s/2,
   a[[1 ;; 2, 1 ;; 2]] = indmat[2*i];
   m = a.m;
   i = 2*i;
   ];
  m
  ]
```

Doesn't work.

```
wavmat[8]
```

This produces the following error message:

```
Dot::rect: Nonrectangular tensor encountered.
```

This may have something to do with the output in my first code sequence at the top of this question?

I am using Mathematica 11.

Comment: @Xavier Thanks for pointing up my mistakes. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this return `{{1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, -(1/2)}}` ?

From the documentation of `Set`, section "Details":

> *`lhs = rhs` returns `rhs` even if for some reason the assignment specified cannot be performed.*

The issue in your code comes from the assignement of the elements of `a` in `wavmat`. You have:

```
a[[1 ;; 2, 1 ;; 2]]
```

while in the preceding code you have

```
a[[1 ;; 2 i, 1 ;; 2 i]]
```

To get the module working, you can write instead `a[[1 ;; 2 Round[i], 1 ;; 2 Round[i]]]`. The `Round` is needed because you are using `Log[n]/Log[2.]`, and the arguments of `Span` need to have the head `Integer`.